# How to couple an Illustrator workspace to an Illustrator template?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, cs5, template-design

I have made a template in Illustrator CS5 as an `.ait` file. Now I am wondering if it is possible to couple a certain workspace (`Drawing`, `Painting`, `Like Freehand`, etc.) to this template such that that workspace is used when the template is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

Illustrator workspaces are entirely independent of any document.

There is no function to tie a workspace to a particular document, template or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this but why don't you drop the `.ait` file in the template folder and when you go to create a new file click on the `Templates` button?

Reference: [Illustrator / Files and templates](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6330a.html)

[image]

or open by clicking at the top and you can select `New from Template` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

[image]

You also didnt specify what version you are using.  If you are using CS6 you can create a Template Layer.

- Reference: [How to create a template layer?](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/888091)
- Tutorial: [How to Create a Template Layer in Adobe Illustrator
  CS6](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-template-layer-in-adobe-illustrato.html)